# use https instead of http

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, https

I am a beginner in java and using tomcat.
I have a requirement where i need to use https instead of http.
My project contains some jsp files in the WebContent. Currently i am accessing the urls over http.
To make it work on https i have referred to the following link

[source](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)

I have followed exact same steps.

1. I have generated a *.keystore file using

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\Users\sanjithkumar017\Desktop\myKey.keystore
   ```

after traversing to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin" using cmd.

2. This is how my server.xml looks.

`<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="C:\Users\sanjithkumar017\Desktop\myKey.keystore" keystorePass="qwerty" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`

And now when i access "https://localhost:8443" on my browser it says "This site can’t be reached".

I had referred to some other links which follow the same steps.but no luck.

I have also tried `telnet localhost 8443`.It says "connect failed".

What am i missing.Please help!!!!!!!

Thanks

jdk::jdk1.7.0_79

tomcat::apache-tomcat-7.0.67

EDIT:: Had forgot to add Java_home in the System variables.Now it works fine.
Thanks guy!!

Comment: Does it help if you use UNIX style forward slash in the keystore path?

Comment: Sorry..silly mistake..forgot to add Java_home..now it works fine.Thanks man